# Understanding cursors, filters and joins in apostrophe

Tags: apostrophe-cms

Trying to work with some data in my widget's html and I've got to a point where I'm stuck, and just trying random things.

If I'm honest the documentation around cursors is just not clear enough for me to understand fully, and I can't find something similar to my case in the source.

So we have some books, and a series of books to which they belong. Books have cover images (and localised cover images but lets not get into that for now). It would seem pretty straight forward to create this setup.

```
//books/index.js
{
  name: '_coverImage',
  label: 'Cover Image',
  type: 'joinByOne',
  withType: 'apostrophe-image',
  idField: 'coverImageId'
},
{
  name: '_bookSeriesGroup',
  label: 'Book Series',
  type: 'joinByOne',
  withType: 'book-series-group',
  idField: 'bookSeriesGroupId',
  withJoins: [
    '_booksGroups._coverImage'
  ],
  filters: {
    projection: {
      title: 1,
      slug: 1,
      _booksGroups: 1,
      _coverImage: 1
    }
  }
} ...
```

Using this I can traverse to the book-series-group in the books-pages/views/show.html:

```
data.piece._bookSeriesGroup
```

However unlike a framework like rails I cannot traverse up and down the relationship to get all books that are in the same group unless I create another joinByArray to books for the book-series-group.

```
//book-series-groups/index.js
{
  name: '_seriesGroupBooks',
  type: 'joinByOneReverse',
  withType: 'book',
  reverseOf: '_bookSeriesGroup'
},
{
  name: '_booksGroups',
  label: 'Books',
  type: 'joinByArray',
  withType: 'book',
  withJoins: ['_coverImage'],
  filters: {
    projection: {
      title: 1,
      blurb: 1,
      position: 1,
      _coverImageId: 1,
      _coverImage: 1,
      _url: 1
    }
  }
}
```

This then lets me follow the relationships like so in the show.html

```
{% for seriesBook in data.piece._bookSeriesGroup._booksGroups %}
  {% set image = apos.images.first(seriesBook._coverImage) %}
  <img class="cover" src="{{ apos.attachments.url(image, {size: 'one-third'}) }}" alt="{{ seriesBook.title }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Ok great, but there are 2 problems with this.

1. Books are assigned to groups in their modal, and then you have to assign them the other way round.
2. The bigger issue is that when I include the withJoins '_booksGroups._coverImage' it loads the correct image instead of the same one every time in the loop (great!) but this in turn breaks any other use of {% set image = apos.images.first(piece._coverImage) %} in the current data.piece or data.pieces loops.

It seemed to me the best way to do this would be simply just to find / filter all the books by the bookSeriesGroupId when in the html, but I cannot figure out how to do this for a whole collection not just the already filtered list for the piece using apos.utils.filter(data.piece.whatever, 'bookSeriesGroupId', theId).

Can you advise how to do this properly please? or some clues?

In the same vein I'm wondering entering joined items into a parent. For example:

```
{
  name: '_bookPublications',
  label: 'Publications',
  type: 'joinByArray',
  withType: 'book-publication',
  filters: {
    projection: {
      title: 1,
      isbn: 1,
      format: 1,
      rrp: 1,
      publicationDate: 1
    }
  }
}
```

On creation we can assign any of the already assigned publications as well as creating new ones. Is there a way to use the filter to only show unassigned publications, as it's massively confusing when there are loads of them!

**Edit**

tl;dr.... How can I work with a filtered collection of all the books in my html?

Comment: Have you looked into joinByOneReverse and joinByArrayReverse?

Comment: I'm not clear on what the problem is with `apos.images.first`. You can use different variable names for each case, there is no need to keep using `image`. But I may be misunderstanding this part.

Comment: Yes see joinByOneReverse in the books-series-groups.... I only want the books to be in one series.

Comment: If you are using reverse joins then there is no UI for setting it "the other way round," it is automatic, it uses the same ids that are already present for the join it is reversing. So are you sure you have to enter these relationships twice?

Comment: Sorry if this is unclear, but I do not want to use 2 relationships if I can avoid it. I would have guessed that creating a joinByOne and it's reverse should allow me to do things like books.bookgroup.books to get all the books from the same group. This doesn't seem to be the functionality with the above joins.

Comment: Why does your `_booksGroups` join exist? Isn't it duplicating `_seriesGroupBooks` while requiring extra UI to set it up? What exactly are you not getting from `_seriesGroupBooks` that requires you to do this?

Comment: It exists because it didn't work at all without.... From the question 'However unlike a framework like rails I cannot traverse up and down the relationship to get all books that are in the same group unless I create another joinByArray to books for the book-series-group.' If I take out that reverse join and try this, it does not find any _seriesGroupBooks in this loop       {% for seriesBook in data.piece._bookSeriesGroup._seriesGroupBooks %} withJoins: [
      '_seriesGroupBooks'], on the joinByOne  seems to make no difference either.

Comment: Seems I can get to the books like this: {% for seriesBook in data.piece._seriesGroupBook[0]._booksGroups %} with the joinByArray and it's reverse. I cannot seem to get past the book series group if it's just a joinByOne

Comment: Please create a test project demonstrating the issue so it's clearer what the context is. Thanks!